# Do you need Page Linking?

Tags: discussion

I happen to know that direct Page Linking functionality is one of our longest standing Enhancement Requests for (SDL) Tridion (Sites).

This Enhancement Request has also been submitted as an [Idea on our SDL Community site](https://community.sdl.com/ideas/sdl-tridion-dx-ideas/sdl-tridion-sites-ideas/i/sdl-tridion-sites-ideas/page-linking), but it didn't get many votes there yet (almost all votes it did get are from the same customer :-)

I'm not sure if this Idea just got unnoticed or if the demand for Page Linking functionality has disappeared over time (I seriously doubt it).

If you are still desperately waiting for Page Linking functionality, please vote for this idea on the SDL Community site (see above link) and please also provide feedback on the questions.

Comment: I take it you mean as a UI feature.

Comment: Indeed. The ability for authors to link to a Page.

Comment: Or the ability for implementers to make this available to authors?

Comment: Please share your thoughts as comments on the Idea.